# QGIS form: relation value

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, valuerelation

I'm building a form to collect observation data of species. I have a layer called "observation" (point) with a field called "observer", it is the name of who sees the species. Secondly, I have a table with all the employees of the company.

In my form, I use a relation value for the field "observer" with my table, so that I have a drop-down menu with all the employees. It works perfectly.

The problem is in my layer "observation", I have many other observers, and they disappeared when I used the relation value, cause they are not in the list.

How can I have a drop-down menu with my employees, for new inputs through the form, but still let me have other "old" records with different employees?

Comment: Is migrating all observers in the proper "observer" table an option ? I think you are mixing two kind of data in a single field, a foreign key to observers, and also some "name and surname of observers", no ?

Comment: No, it is not possible, cause I would have really a lot of observers. I don't think I'm mixing two kind of fields. I have one field in my table called "name". And one field in the layer "observation" called "name". The relation is made between them simply like that: name<->name. So in the form of the layer observation, for "name", I use "relation value"... and I works, I have the correct dropdown list! The problem is that the old names are not in the table "observer", so they disappear in the attribute table. I don't want the old name in the dropdown list.

Comment: To be honest, I can't migrate all the observers the the table. The reason is that the layer "observation" collects records from employees (so I need the dropdown list). But I also received datas from other peoples (outside the company), and I append these records to the main layer. So I would have to update the "observer" table each time I receive new datas. So if we digitalize new data in qgis (using form), only the employees, but if I use "append" for outside company data, it can be anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the "old" field with the old observers, then create a new field with value relation that you use for new oberservs: those you take with value relation from the table. So you have a clean dataset and don't have to mix old and new observers with the risk of altering data.

You can define a constraint in the "new" field so that if the "old" field already contains a name, it should stay empty.

To combine both old and new observer values, create a 3rd field as virtual filed that dynamically updates and that combines both fields, like:

```
if (length ("name_old") > 0, "name_old",  represent_value ("name_new"))
```

This field is what you're looking for as it combines bot manually entered values as well as the names from the value relation.

[image]

Comment: I had the same idea, by having a "temp_observer", that I use for new records with only the active employees. The field "observer" would have a default value as "temp_observer".